# How to use the Play template as a SQL template?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I wish to store my long SQL in a Play Framework template, then I can supply parameters to the template. How can I do this? What is a good way to do this?

Comment: Using Anorm or Slick, you have SQL string interpolation, which allow to mix Scala expressions/values in large string. Even if that's not in a separate file as it would be with a template file, I think that's a nice way to go.

Comment: Play templates are meant for views and view fragments. Storing SQL there doesn't really make sense, since it's part of the model layer. What you're describing is no different than a typical model function. If you're finding yourself needing to use the same query for different methods, you might want to consider why you they aren't collapsed into one function anyway.